# Transcribe a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this kind of list of dictionary in python

```
[
  {
    "compania": "Fiat",
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "1000"
  },
  {
    "compania": "Renault",
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "2000"
  },
  {
    "compania": "Volkwagen",
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "3000"
  },
  {
    "compania": "Chevrolet",
     "modelo": "2014",    
     "precio": "1000"    
  },
  {
    "compania": "Peugeot",
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "2000"
  } 
]
```

That I'd like to transform into this kind of list of list of dictionary

```
{   
  "Fiat": {
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "1000"
  },
  "Renault": {
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "2000"
  },
  "Volkwagen": {
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "3000"
  },
  "Chevrolet": {
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "1000"
  },
  "Peugeot": {
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "2000"
  }  
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Also note that your output is a dictionary mapping strings to dictionaries, not a list of list of dictionaries.

Comment: So what have you tried? This seems fairly easy, just taking out the `d['compania']`  from each element of the list and creating a dictionary with it and with rest of the key value pairs being its contents.

Comment: Yes, I am very noob  with these issues. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We can use dict comprehension

```
{a.get('compania'): {k: v for k, v in a.items() if k != 'compania'} for a in c}

{'Fiat': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '1000'},
 'Renault': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '2000'},
 'Volkwagen': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '3000'},
 'Chevrolet': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '1000'},
 'Peugeot': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '2000'}}
```

where `c` is your original data

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary by iterating over the elements of your original list. Assuming your list is called `car_list`:

```
d = { x["compania"]: {"modelo": x["modelo"], "precio": x["precio"] } for x in car_list }
```

Comment: Thanks, I work, some book or paper that deals with these issues, I am very new.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is called `l`, you could accomplish this using simple iteration and building a new dictionary `d`:

```
d = {}

for sub in l:
  d[sub.pop('compania')] = sub
```

This produces in the dictionary `d`:

```
{'Chevrolet': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '1000'},
 'Fiat': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '1000'},
 'Peugeot': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '2000'},
 'Renault': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '2000'},
 'Volkwagen': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '3000'}}
```

Explanation: For each dictionary in that list (`sub`): `sub.pop('compania')` deletes the entry of the key 'compania' in `sub` and returns it's associated value. We are then updating the dictionary `d` to have a key of what was just returned and we are associating with that key, the remainder of `sub` after the deletion of that entry.

Comment: Why would you use a destructive operations like `.pop` here? Is there any advantage? In general, unless you are trying to remove things, I would err on the side of *not* removing things.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga simply because `pop` succinctly returns the key we want for the new dictionary, and after it is carried out, leaves behind what the value associated to that key should be. I do see where you are coming from though :)

Answer (score 0):

with a mapper function to return a new customized list of dicts

```
a=[
  {
    "compania": "Fiat",
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "1000"
  },
  {
    "compania": "Renault",
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "2000"
  },
  {
    "compania": "Volkwagen",
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "3000"
  },
  {
    "compania": "Chevrolet",
     "modelo": "2014",    
     "precio": "1000"    
  },
  {
    "compania": "Peugeot",
    "modelo": "2014",    
    "precio": "2000"
  } 
]  

def mapper(temp): # define a mapper
    new_temp={}
    new_temp[temp['compania']]={k:v for k,v in temp.items() if k!='compania'}
    return new_temp

map(mapper,a) # call map function with mapper and list as argument
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {}
for d in l:
    # Store the value of the key 'compania' before popping it from the small dictionary d
    compania = d['compania']
    d.pop('compania')
    # Construct new dictionary with key of the compania and value of the small dictionary without the compania key/value pair
    result[compania] = d
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'Chevrolet': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '1000'},
 'Fiat': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '1000'},
 'Peugeot': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '2000'},
 'Renault': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '2000'},
 'Volkwagen': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '3000'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would share simple solution:

```
>>> {d.pop("compania"):d for d in dd}
```

Comment: don't use `.pop` in a comprehension construct, it has a side effect, and you should avoid side-effects in functional constructs.

Comment: Precisely because the solution uses a side effect it is short in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use dictionary [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) which can then produce a new dictionary of your preference.

```
from pprint import PrettyPrinter as pp
d={}
for i in l: # 'l' represents your list of dictionary 
    d.update({i['compania']:{"modelo":i['modelo'],"precio":i['precio']}})
print(pp(indent=4).pprint(d))
```

> ouput:

```
{   'Chevrolet': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '1000'},
'Fiat': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '1000'},
'Peugeot': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '2000'},
'Renault': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '2000'},
'Volkwagen': {'modelo': '2014', 'precio': '3000'}}
```